# Android - How to send data back to the calling activity

Tags: android-intent, android-activity

I am calling activityB from activityA and passing a class object using intent.

```
Intent intentB = new Intent(v.getContext(), activityB.class);
intentB.putExtra("data", data); //data is a class object
startActivity(intentB);
```

The activityB starts fine and also I am able to extract data.  In activityB, I am modifying the data object.  I want to send this modified data object back to activityA when activityB.onDestroy() is called.

Any advice?

Here is my code:

activityA, starting the `Intent`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, activityB.class);
i.putExtra("object", Class.object);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

activityA, catching the intent:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == 1) {    
        object = data.getParcelableExtra("object"); //the Class implements Parcelable
  }
}
```

activityB

```
protected void onDestroy() {
  Intent data = new Intent();
  setResult(RESULT_OK, data) 
  finish(); // ends current activity
}
```

Comment: I honestly think you're better to just have an interface - it's very easy https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make use of the ActivityResult.

1. Use `startActivityForResult(int, Intent)`
2. To set information in Activity B, use `setResult(RESULT_OK, data)` (where data is an Intent)
3. Override `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` and catch the `data`-Intent

Activity A, starting the `Intent`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Activity A, catching the data:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (requestCode == 1) {    
        // make use of "data" = profit
  }
}
```

Activity B:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, data) 
finish(); // ends current activity
```

Comment: Where should I set the data intent in activityB?  I tried setting it in `activityB.onDestroy()`, but Intent data in `activityA.onActivityResult()` is null